# how a thread pool can be used and destroyed after use

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, web-worker

I am trying to create multiple threads based on my request. When I execute the below code, I am getting error as

> RESULT: [Error: ReferenceError: doEncode is not defined] null

Here is a summary of my problem:

- Run doEncode() function in every 0.1 second
- destroy the thread once all process is completed

Here is my code
File1.js

```
var threadCount = 4;
var threadPool  = require('webworker-threads').createPool(threadCount);

threadPool.load('File2.js');
threadPool.all.emit('init');

threadPool.on('message', function threadMessage(data) {
    console.log(this.id + ': ' + data);
});


// Every 0.2 seconds we need to check
setInterval( checkForJobs, 200 );

// Every 0.1 second we need to enqueue
setInterval( enqueueJob, 100 );

function enqueueJob () {
    threadPool.any.eval('doEncode()', function(err, ok){
        console.log("RESULT:");
        console.log(err, ok);
        if(ok)
            threadPool.destroy();
    });
}

function checkForJobs() {
    if (threadPool.idleThreads() == 0) {
        /* We have no threads to run the encode on so dont bother */
        console.log('!!! No threads');
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log('idle threads: ', threadPool.idleThreads());
    }
}
```

File2.js

```
var value = require("./common");
function File2() {

}
File2.prototype.doEncode = function () {
    var i = 0, g = 0;
    console.log('[' + thread.id + '] Starting encode ');
    while (i++ < 10000000) {
        if (i == 200) {
            console.log('-- here 200');
        }
        if (i == 400) {
            console.log('-- here 400');
        }
        if (i == 500) {
            console.log('-- here 500');
        }

        g = value.t(i) * value.t(i + 1);
    }
    console.log('++++ done ' + g);
    return g;
}

module.exports = File2
```

common.js

```
function t(i) {
    return i / 65 * 3;
}

exports.t = t;
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here or can I achieve the same by using child_process? Which one of the methods can give better performance without memory leak?

Comment: I think you can achieve the same with node's `cluster.fork` or `child_process.fork`. But I don't understand why you are destroying a thread if you want to keep it running at every .1 sec. The error is obvious, you need call `(new File2()).doEncode() `

Comment: @hassansin I have tried (new File2()).doEncode() in my posted code but still facing the error RESULT:
[Error: TypeError: Object #<File2> has no method 'doEncode'] null